# Problem wiring a nodejs express back-end with a reactjs front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to put together a reactjs Dashboard and wire it up with a Nodejs back-end. I am currently trying to validate a jwt token. when I do it using a Postman app, its working fine. but when I try it using my reactjs form, its not happening. please help me find the problem in my code. I am not an experienced developer. I am kind of a newbie to both nodejs and reactjs.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
I will try to post all the relevant code and some snapshots below.

```
//reactjs code calling this function on a button submit
 //verify user

  onVerify = event => {
    let databody = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(databody);
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/me", {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "x-access-token": databody
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong with your fetch");
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json.token);
      });
  };
```

Nodejs express backend code

```
//app.js
var express = require("express");

var db = require("./db");
var Cors = require("cors");

var app = express();

app.use(Cors());

var UserController = require("./user/UserController");
app.use("/users", UserController);

var AuthController = require("./auth/AuthController");
app.use("/api/auth", AuthController);

var WorkInvenController = require("./auth/WorkInvenController");
app.use("/api/workinven", WorkInvenController);

module.exports = app;
```

```
//AuthController.js


router.get("/me", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  var token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
  if (!token)
    return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, message: "No token provided." });

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.secret, function(err, decoded) {
    if (err)
      return res
        .status(500)
        .send({ auth: false, message: "Failed to authenticate token." });

    User.findById(decoded.id, { password: 0 }, function(err, user) {
      if (err)
        return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the user.");
      if (!user) return res.status(404).send("No user found.");

      res.status(200).send(user);
    });
  });
});
```

terminal output from the backend when posted using Postman

[image]

terminal output from the backend when posted using reactjs from

[image]

browser error attached below
[image]

Comment: what is the issue you are facing exactly? both the terminal out puts are same, and its just the request details. how can you say its not working  and what it should do when working?

Comment: sorry  about that .. I have modified the post to add the browser error.

Comment: this means, your api is giving error with status code 500, can you see in the network tab ? api call  response?

Comment: I did try the same with a postman and it works fine... so I guess the fetch call that I make from the reactjs end is wrong ... or Is there a problem with my headers?

Comment: Can you also add here the fetch request details from the Browser's Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

as i can see its a "rejection error"

you can just add `.catch()` and handle the error that is being thrown.

```
onVerify = event => {
    let databody = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(databody);
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/me", {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "x-access-token": databody
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong with your fetch");
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json.token);
      }).catch(error=>{
     //handle the error in here may be
        console.log(error)
     });
  };
```

sometime we wrote some sort of wrapper as well to handle errors:

```
fetch(<url>, {
      <headers>,
     <options>
    })
      .then(this._checkStatus)
      .then(response => response.json());

 _checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      // Success status lies between 200 to 300
      return response;
    }  else {
//here handle the error may be.
      var error = new Error(response.statusText);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

so in your case, when the error coming its not handled , as there no .catch found, its throwing unhandled rejection error.
you can look at the above methods and follow any of them , also let me know if you are still facing issue with this.

Comment: any idea what is causing this error in the first place? why am I  not getting this error when I make a call using Postman?

Comment: in you frontend you are facing the error, when trying to fetch. and you didnt handle those error [even status code 500 gives error], so its coming up. above i showed how to handle.
and in postman, you are actually hitting the api directly, so its showing what it gates as its,

Comment: I tried to catch the error using your code .. but its not working for me.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: if my call is correct I should be getting the user details back .. which I am not getting

Comment: yaa I am getting the user back when validating my token .. kinda strange right?

Comment: @rpserverbox right, may be in postman, can you check what is the response status code its responding with? like 200 or something?

Comment: I tried to get the error from server directly and its  ``` " name: 'TokenExpiredError',
  message: 'jwt expired',
  expiredAt: 2019-04-29T20:48:51.000Z } ```. but then I used the same token to verify thorugh Postman and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that I didn't post the whole code up here, or else I am sure you guys would have figured it long time back. long story short..
the problem was with my token, I accidentally set the expiresIn to 60 thinking that it was 60 minutes instead of 60 * 60. so the token was expiring every next minute.

Now after setting the token expiry to "24h" everything seems working good..
thanks a lot for you help guys.